# Can I play videos FROM PC on Phone

Tags: kodi

I have installed Kodi, and my question is:

Is it possible to play videos from computer to my phone? I mean kodi running on PC and on my phone plays videos from my PC hard drive as streamed accross lan/wlan.

If not with Kodi, with other?

I dont have money for NAS, media server.

Answer (score 1):

With [Kodi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodi_%28software%29) on both devices, you should be able to do so via [Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), which is widely supported:

> Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) is a set of networking protocols that
>   permits networked devices, such as personal computers, printers,
>   Internet gateways, Wi-Fi access points and mobile devices to
>   seamlessly discover each other's presence on the network and establish
>   functional network services for data sharing, communications, and
>   entertainment. UPnP is intended primarily for residential networks
>   without enterprise-class devices. ... The UPnP architecture allows device-to-device networking of consumer electronics, mobile devices, personal computers, and networked home appliances.

UPNP can be used for sharing videos from a PC to other devices using [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/) as explained at [HOW-TO:Share libraries using UPnP](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Share_libraries_using_UPnP), which notes:

> UPnP sharing between two Kodi devices is the easiest way to share a
>   library. You can also share multiple libraries, one from each Kodi
>   device, to all the other devices on the same network. UPnP also takes
>   care of file sharing, so you do not need to do anything extra even if
>   your files are added locally to Kodi.

You can configure the PC to act as a UPnP media server and then on the phone configure it to use the PC as a [media source](http://kodi.wiki/view/UPnP/Media_source).

Similar UPnP functionality is offered by [TVersity Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TVersity_Media_Server), which functions as a UPnP A/V and [Digital Living Network Alliance (DLNA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) Media Server; there are [free and commercial versions](http://tversity.com/download/#MediaServer) of that software.

Comment: It's perfect thank you very much!
One more thing: If i play for example a video and i have subtitle for it, how can i get the subtitle streamed?

Comment: @Shapperd, perhaps [Subtitles](http://kodi.wiki/view/Subtitles), which has information about Kodi's subtitle settings may help. Also see [HOW-TO:Set up subtitle services](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Set_up_subtitle_services).